Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code
I've built a console app which will start as a Windows service but also has a REST API implemented. Unfortunately, when I make a request in the web browser:

http://localhost:5000/api/v1/article/1

I get a 404 in the .NET console:

Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being
handled by application code.

My Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("schedules.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var config = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyApp.DAL.DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("mydbconn"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyApp.DAL")));

builder.Services.AddWindowsService();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IArticleService, ArticleService>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyApp.DAL.DataContext>();
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}

app.Run();

My API controller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApp.API.Models;
using MyApp.Exchange.Services;

namespace MyApp.Exchange.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Manages articles.
    /// </summary>
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ArticleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IArticleService _articleService;

        public ArticleController(IArticleService articleService)
        {
            _articleService = articleService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetArticles(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return Ok(await _articleService.GetAllArticles(cancellationToken));
        }

        [HttpGet("/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetArticle(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var article = await _articleService.GetArticle(id, cancellationToken);
            if (article is null)
                return NotFound();
            else
                return Ok(article);
        }
    }
}

Why aren't the endpoints getting hit?

Ok, I figured it out. In the endpoint where I provide an id, I should provide the route without the prefixed slash.
[HttpGet("{id}")] // correct!

instead of
[HttpGet("/{id}")] // wrong!

The endpoint without any parameters actually works.
